# How to pass id value from modal window to click ajax event?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a table with photos, when I click on the image a modal window opens in which I want to update the image. To check if the id of the image is correct I made an alert window and in this window the correct id is shown. I want to update the image using the ajax method, but I can't pass id to ajax, I made an alert window to look at and it throws -> undefined.
How can pass id to ajax for further work with it?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var wrap = $('#wrapper'),
    modal = $('.overlay, .modal, .content_modal');

    $('.open_modal_btn').click(function(event) { //open modal window
        modal.fadeIn();
        alert(  $(this).attr('data-id')); //shows the correct id
        var id = $(this).data('id'); //assign id to a variable

        $("#ajax_update").on('submit',(function(e) { //pressing save button after selecting an image from a folder
          e.preventDefault();
          alert(id); // here no longer shows id, shows undefined
          var fd = new FormData();
          var files = $('#file').files;
          fd.append('file',files);
          fd.append('request',1);
          fd.append('id', id);
          $.ajax({
            url: "./update_photo.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  fd,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data){
              if(data=='invalid'){
                // invalid file format
                console.log(data);
              }else{
                // view uploaded file
                $("#photo").attr('src',"../api/img/"+data).fadeIn();
                $("#ajax_update").reset();
                console.log(data);
              }
            },
            error: function(e){
              console.log(data);
            }
          });
        }));
      });

$('.modal').click(function() { // close modal window
  wrap.on('click', function(event) {
    var select = $('.content_modal');
    if ($(event.target).closest(select).length)
      return;
    modal.fadeOut();
    wrap.unbind('click');
  });
});
});
```

file php

```
if($request == 1){ 
        $id= $_POST['id']; //id from ajax request
```

Comment: Declare `var id` globally outside your event handler and check ones

Comment: Please explain how can I do this if my id is dynamic and depends on the click, i.e. when clicking on a certain element, there will be a certain id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `$(this).attr('data-id')` and `$(this).data('id')` interchangeably.
`FormData.append` takes a File object as a second parameter, not a FileList.
You can pass the button id to the callback function via the data parameter.

```
$('.open_modal_btn').click(function(event) { //open modal window
    modal.fadeIn();

    $("#ajax_update").on('submit', {id: $(this).attr('data-id')}, (function(e) { //pressing save button after selecting an image from a folder
      e.preventDefault();
      alert(e.data.id); // here no longer shows id, shows undefined
      var fd = new FormData();
      var file = $('#file').files[0]; //assuming you're uploading 1 file
      fd.append('file',file);
      fd.append('request',1);
      fd.append('id', e.data.id);
      $.ajax({
        url: "./update_photo.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:  fd,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data){
          if(data=='invalid'){
            // invalid file format
            console.log(data);
          }else{
            // view uploaded file
            $("#photo").attr('src',"../api/img/"+data).fadeIn();
            $("#ajax_update").reset();
            console.log(data);
          }
        },
        error: function(e){
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
    }));
  });
```